# How to make one div increase height while shrinking another div?

Tags: jquery, css

There is a great [plugin](http://takien.github.io/jPushMenu/) which allows one to slide in a menu from the side and push the body out of the way. I like the option of having the panel slide in from the bottom (Toggle Bottom Menu), but I'd like two changes:

1. The newly displayed panel must remain in position until the same button (used to toggle it) is clicked again, making it slide away.
2. The new panel must, as it slides in, shrink the other element from bottom to top (I want to choose the element myself). I don't want to push the body... just shrink an arbitrary element.

An example of the markup would be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
                <a href="sliding-panel">Toggle Sliding panel!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="myMap"></div>
            <div id="sliding-panel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking the link/href would cause the sliding-panel to grow vertically, while the map would shrink to a minimum height (about 300px).

Is there a plugin which does this? If not, how can I do this? Happy to use JQuery or a CSS-only option.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: *The newly displayed panel must remain in position until the same button (used to toggle it) is clicked again, making it slide away.* If you look at jPushMenu's [source code](https://github.com/takien/jPushMenu/blob/master/js/jPushMenu.js), there is an option to do this - `closeOnClickOutside`. When jPushMenu is initialized, you can define `closeOnClickOutside` as `false` (by default, it is `true`).

For your second question: *The new panel must, as it slides in, shrink the other element from bottom to top (I want to choose the element myself). I don't want to push the body... just shrink an arbitrary element.* It's impossible to only use jPushMenu and implement what you want. No library can do this as there are several logic that must be handled manually:

- What kind of *shrink* animation you want.
- Which element(s) should be shrinked.

However, you can listen to toggle menu's `click` event and make the *shrink* work yourself.

In summary, the feature in these 2 questions can be implemented with the following code snippet:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.toggle-menu').jPushMenu({
      closeOnClickOutside: false
    });

    $('.toggle-menu').on('click', function() {
      if($(this).hasClass('menu-active')) {
        // menu slides in, need to shrink some elements.
      } else {
        // menu slides out, need to put these elements back.
      }
    });
  });
```